# iOS UINavagationController stack go infinite when you press fast enough

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem

I setup a simple `UINavigationController` with three scene, then control drag the `UIBarButtonItem` to every next scene. Simplest setup.

When I run in simulator, and press very fast to the next scene, it like spawning some extra last scene. Look at the GIF below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oixa.jpg

Is this normal? or I do it wrongly?

---

**Edit 1:** It appear when I setup the `UIBarButtonItem` with the same labeling, it will cause the spawning of extra scene. Not when I give them a unique labeling, or at least different from the next scene.

Comment: You might try calling the segue programmatically to see if this still happen

Comment: you mean hook up the button with code to trigger to next scene?

Comment: yep, for the activity in yours im also not sure why also, probably in simulator the touch is much faster with mouse than in real with finger so it might be the issue

Comment: i give every scene a tile and unique button labeling, the problem gone away. https://i.imgur.com/QbiZhkE.png